# Does Turtlebot supported on groovy?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I just finished installing ros-groovy on my Ubuntu.
Does Turtlebot supported in ros-groovy?

I found that no "ros-groovy-turtlebot-desktop" exist while I following tutorial below.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/SDK%20Setup/Deb

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52866/does-turtlebot-supported-on-groovy?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-20**:
Btw, please use tags as much as possible! It makes it easier for others to find questions and answers about topics they are interested and/or skilled in. I added the turtlebot and groovy tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Are you using Turtlebot 1 or 2? Groovy support for the T1 (Create and Roomba) is currently worked on. T2 (Kobuki) should already be running. We are targeting support of both with the 2.0 release. Please be patient - or even better - help the TurtleBot community and join the development! :-)

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0